# Why are curly braces not interpreted by surrounding backticks in Perl?

Tags: perl, bash

```
my @cmd=`ls {??_in,??}.pl`;
print @cmd;
```

If run that program it say error

```
    `ls: cannot access {??_in,??}.pl: No such file or directory`
```

now same it has run on terminal

`cmd>ls {??,??_in}.pl`

`cmd>aa_in.pl  aa.pl  ls.pl`

so its produce output in commad line, why in perl not consider that curly brace.

Comment: The curly braces are interpreted by the shell, not by the `ls` command. You can try invoking the command through a shell, like `bash -c 'ls {??,??_in}.pl'`

Comment: perl simply `exec`s the command that you give without the shell coming into the picture.  On the other hand, it's the shell that performs globbing.

Comment: Is perl using the same shell that you are using?  Bash vs csh perhaps?

Comment: @Bill Ruppert, Perl always uses `/bin/sh` except on Windows

Comment: @devnull: The shell _does_ enter the picture here (implicitly via `/bin/sh -c`), because the command string contains (unquoted) instances of what the Perl documentation loosely calls shell metacharacters; in this case, `?` and `{` and `}` - see `perldoc -f system`.
The most likely reason it doesn't work here is that the OP's `sh` doesn't recognize brace expansion (which is a Bash/Ksh/Zsh extension), so the pattern matches nothing and is treated as a literal, as since explained in [dataless' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21650187/45375).

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Perl's `glob` built-in](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) to get that list of files instead doing a system call to `ls`.

```
use Data::Dump;
dd [ glob '{??_in,??}.pl' ];
```

Will print a list of files matching the pattern. The `glob` will take care of filling in the wildcards and finding the files.

---

Also note that you are assigning the return value of the backticks to the scalar variable `$cmd`, but you are trying to print the array `@cmd`. Those are different variables. It will also result in an error *Global symbol "@cmd" requires explicit package name...* if you have `use strict` turned on (which you should do!).

Comment: Why? What's the gain on that?

Comment: I need why is not working, why its consider given expression as filename.. if using system function that time also it say same error.without using {} its working fine...

Comment: See the comments http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645261/why-are-curly-braces-not-interpreted-by-surrounding-backticks-in-perl#comment32712343_21645261 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645261/why-are-curly-braces-not-interpreted-by-surrounding-backticks-in-perl#comment32712355_21645261 by *user000001* and *devnull* on your question. They explain why it is not working. My solution will work with pure Perl, no need to do the system call.

Answer (score 6):

I think it's based on which shell gets invoked.  You are using bash-specific brace expansion, not supported by the POSIX shell.

On my system, I get these results:

```
$ perl -e '`sh -c "ls src/{*.pl,*.h}"` and print "success\n"'
ls: cannot access src/{*.pl,*.h}: No such file or directory

$ perl -e '`bash -c "ls src/{*.pl,*.h}"` and print "success\n"'
success
```

So, my conclusion is perl is calling 'sh'.  You can get around it by using "bash -c" like in my example.

Comment: Or simply use `glob "{??,??_in}.pl"`. Less overheard, works on all systems.

Comment: Its true there are lots of better ways to solve the problem.  However, his confusion was related to the shell being invoked, and that is what my answer is about.

Comment: Of course. But it's always good to mention a better way after explaining the problem.